# How to sort gunichar in Glib::ustring?

Tags: c++, sorting, glib

I am trying to sort characters in `Glib::ustring` by their Unicode position. The following code:

```
Glib::ustring str("hello");
std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
```

produces the following error at compile time:

```
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_algo.h:1975:22: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘Glib::ustring_Iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’ and ‘Glib::ustring_Iterator<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >’)
 1975 |     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
```

My understanding is that sort is trying to get the difference between the first and last characters (i.e. the length of the container), but it is not defined by `Glib::ustring_Iterator`.

I can get around the problem by copying into some other container, and the putting it back:

```
Glib::ustring str("hello");
std::vector<gunichar> vec(str.begin(), str.end());
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
str.assign(Glib::ustring{vec.begin(), vec.end()});
```

But this code feels like an ugly hack for a feature that i would expect to see in the library, but perhaps just not looking in the right place. Is this wheel already implemented?

Comment: There is no such functionality because a string is not an array of characters. It is internally represented as an array of code units (bytes). It makes no sense to sort such array. You can view it as a sequence of Unicode characters but this sequence is not random-access.

Comment: @n.m. I am *not* trying to sort the array of bytes from the internal representation. I am looking for a way to sort the characters themselves. If i wasn't clear, i apologise.

Comment: No, it was very clear. You are trying to sort characters. The problem is that the array found in the representation is not made of characters, and the characters are not stored in an array or in another form that is easy to sort. This is the reason why you cannot subtract the iterators.